# consecutive lines without changing order

Tags: awk, grep

```
cat file1
4    
8     
7  

cat file2
4.999286    12.669064   0.000000  
5.999343    12.753258   0.000000  
6.999401    12.654514   0.000000  
7.999458    12.774485   0.000000  
8.999515    12.662147   0.000000  
9.999572    12.700071   0.000000  
10.999629   12.717721   0.000000
```

I am looking to grep file1 with the same order and two more consecutive lines. I tried this:

```
grep -A 2 -Ff file1 file2
```

I want the output like this:

```
4.999286    12.669064   0.000000  
5.999343    12.753258   0.000000  
6.999401    12.654514   0.000000  
8.999515    12.662147   0.000000  
9.999572    12.700071   0.000000  
10.999629   12.717721   0.000000  
7.999458    12.774485   0.000000  
8.999515    12.662147   0.000000  
9.999572    12.700071   0.000000
```

Comment: Could you please check my answer once if that helped you here?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU [grep](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html) & [parallel](https://zenodo.org/record/1146014)):

```
parallel -k grep -A2 '^{}' file2 :::: file1
```

Grep file2 multiple times in parallel using file1 as input and keep the original order.

Or if you prefer,as:

```
parallel -a file1 -k grep -A2 '^{}' file2
```

Or:

```
cat file1 | parallel -k grep -A2 '^{}' file2
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is fast for few file scans

```
$ while IFS= read -r n; do grep -A2 "^$n." file2; done < file1

4.999286 12.669064 0.000000
5.999343 12.753258 0.000000
6.999401 12.654514 0.000000
8.999515 12.662147 0.000000
9.999572 12.700071 0.000000
10.999629 12.717721 0.000000
7.999458 12.774485 0.000000
8.999515 12.662147 0.000000
9.999572 12.700071 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, this will give results in same order in which `$1` occurs in Input_file1.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
(int($1) in a){
  system("grep -A2 " s1 $0 s1 OFS FILENAME)
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                             ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                            ##Starting BEGIN section of code here.
  s1="\""                                         ##Creating a variable named s1 whose value is "
}                                                 ##Closing BEGIN section of awk code here.
FNR==NR{                                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR, which will be only TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$0]                                           ##Creating an array named a whose index is $0.
  next                                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                 ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
(int($1) in a){                                   ##Checking condition if integer value of $1 is present in array a then do following.
  system("grep -A2 " s1 $0 s1 OFS FILENAME)       ##Using system command to run grep command which will print 2 lines after match of current line in current Input_file name passed to grep by FILENAME variable of awk.
}                                                 ##Closing BLOCK of condition.
'  Input_file1  Input_file2                       ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
4.999286 12.669064 0.000000
5.999343 12.753258 0.000000
6.999401 12.654514 0.000000
7.999458 12.774485 0.000000
8.999515 12.662147 0.000000
9.999572 12.700071 0.000000
8.999515 12.662147 0.000000
9.999572 12.700071 0.000000
10.999629 12.717721 0.000000
```

Comment: @Mohd, Could you please do let me know if this helps you?