# Save output file each run in a loop

Tags: bash

I just want to change one number inside a file then run it and save the output file. This need to be done in an iterative way.

cat file1

```
decay=(  1 5 2 6 )
for i in $decay
do
    run   file2.i
done
```

cat file2.i

```
cell 215 cell 115 cell ${i}
```

So now for each decay(i), I need file2.i to use the decay(i). Also, the output file will always have the same name file2.i_outp. How to save the output file each run instead of overwriting each i.

Comment: @Barmar, it is part of a ```for``` loop!

Comment: @accdias It wasn't when I wrote the comment.

Comment: True, I modified the file1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the template `file2.i` to a temporary file, replacing `${decay}` with the current array element.

```
decay=(1 5 2 6)
for i in $decay
do
    sed "s/\\${i}/$i/" file2.i > /tmp/file2.i.$$
    run /tmp/file2.i.$$
    rm /tmp/file2.i.$$
done > file2.i_outp
```

Comment: It works good but it seems only use the first i which is 1 here.

Comment: I don't understand why. Each time through the loop it replaces `${i}` in the file with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked fine

```
for i in {1 5 2 6}
do
    sed "s/\\${i}/$i/" file2.i > /tmp/file2.i.$$
    run /tmp/file2.i.$$
    rm /tmp/file2.i.$$
done > file2.i_outp
```

Comment: Hi Mohd, could you please check my solution to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58350660/5866580 and let me know if that helped you there.